# Выкидывает из приложения и создает левый apk файл

Tags: android, kotlin, apk

У меня есть приложение - такси, в проекте изначально было 3 приложения :Common - библиотека: :Driver - для водителей :Rider - для пассажиров

Следующей задачей было объединить эти два приложения (водитель и пассажир) в одно. Я создал четвертое приложение: лаунчер ... переписал проект водителя и пассажира как com.android.library и соединил их.

```
dependencies {
    api project(':common')
    api project(':rider')
    // api project(':driver') для начало взял только Rider
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Сначала добавил только проект для пассажира и попробовал запустить через лаунчер, для этого создал fun GoRider, который должен отправлять на страницу авторизации пассажиров

```
fun GoRider(view: View) {
    val intent = Intent(this, com.innomalist.taxi.rider.activities.splash.SplashRiderActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

После компиляции и запуска релиза приложения показывает MainActivity экрана лаунчера, нажимаем кнопку с функцией GoRider, приложение переходит в режим авторизации, после авторизации приложение ломается и выкидывает на главный экран

А также создаются 2 дополнительных приложения для водителя и пассажира, как это исправить (должно быть только одно приложение Launcher)

Напишите, какие исходники предоставить

Comment: если выкидывает из приложения, значит где-то ошибка. Вкладка Logact - там будет много красного текста во время падения, приложите лог падения в вопрос и тогда будет более понятно где искать проблему

Comment: C радостью предоставил бы, но я использую firebase, а без подписи SHA-1 в дебаге я не смогу запустить, дабы посмотреть логи, если подскажете как мне это сделать с радостью выложу весь LogCat

Comment: как это без подписи в дебаге? что-то не очень понял)) вы когда запускаете приложение на устройстве то оно падает, во время падения логи будут в студии и наверное что-то прилетит в firebase тоже